# Call to undefined function password_hash()

Tags: php, password-encryption, password-hash, php-password-hash, undefined-function

I am running php version 5.4.16 on localhost right now, while I am developing my site.  I want to use `password_hash()`, but I keep getting this error:

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined function password_hash() in **/dir/to/file.php** on line **123**

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 31):

The new `password_*` methods are only available as of PHP 5.5:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Take a look at this library that provides forward compatibility:

https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

You can use that to get access to the new `password_*` methods until you are able to run PHP 5.5.

Comment: What are the alternatives in older versions of PHP?

Comment: for older versions use crypt() http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php You can use hashes made with password_hash together with crypt