# how to fix this error : Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_hash()

Tags: php

I will like to hash the password entered by the user but I get this error[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpZpY.png)[my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1e0yt.png)

Comment: Hi, can you show the line that make  this error, [line 14]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955465/call-to-undefined-function-password-hash

Comment: the error is on line 14

Comment: My guess is that you are using an old version of PHP. The `password_hash` function is available starting with PHP `5.5`.

Comment: yes I am using an older version of php ....
I then used crypt () instead of password_hash ()
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php
thank you...